# How to make DetailView change data by indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, master-detail

I'm currently working on a Master-DetailView application and I'm stuck on how to make the data change....

I saw a great tutorial on how to do this :

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6Wl8ySrOZI&t=312s)

But the guy is using a blank ViewController & I'm using a TableViewController With static Cells,So it doesn't work.

I want to put the data manually like

```
var Label1Data = ["You Tapped Cell 1,You Tapped Cell 2,You Tapped Cell 3"]
```

and it will show in the DetailView by the index path if i pressed the first cell the first data will show up in that Label...i know its not ideal to use static cells here but i do wanna use them design wise.

It will be great if any one could show me finally how can i put the data successfully like i said above and how the Tutorial does it.

## MasterViewController Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class BarsViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var tableViewController: UITableView!
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var sel_val : String?

    // TableView Data :

struct User {
        var name: String
        var streetName: String
        var image: UIImage?
    }

var allUsers: [User]!
    var filteredUsers: [User]!

    func createUsers(names: [String], streets: [String], images: [UIImage?]) -> [User] {
        var users = [User]()
        guard names.count == streets.count && names.count == images.count else { return users }
        for (index, name) in names.enumerated() {
            let user = User(name: name, streetName: streets[index], image: images[index])
            users.append(user)
        }
        return users
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if tableView == self.tableView {

        return self.names.count

        } else {
            return self.filteredUsers.count
        }

    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        let user:User!

        if tableView == self.tableView {
            user = allUsers[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.photo.image = user.image
        cell.name.text = user.name
        cell.streetName.text = user.streetName

        return cell
    }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){


        let object = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BarProfileTableViewController") as! BarsProfile
        let user:User!
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            user = allUsers[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
        }

      print("username : \(user.name)")
        print("streetName : \(user.streetName)")

        MyIndex = indexPath.row

        object.barImage = user.image!
        object.barName = user.name
        object.streetName = user.streetName



        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(object, animated: true)

    }
```

## DetailView's Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MapKit

class BarsProfile: UITableViewController,MKMapViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var Distance: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var headerImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var OnlineMenu: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Address: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ProfileMapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet var BarNameLBL: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var streetNameLBL: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var MusicLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var KindOfBarCell: UITableViewCell!



    var barName = String()
    var barImage = UIImage()
    var streetName = String()


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        BarNameLBL.text = barName
        streetNameLBL.text = streetName
        navigationItem.title = barName


    }
```

## How it looks like : ( Red line is a label i would like to put data manually in)

[image]

Comment: question is not understandable

Comment: What the tutorial does but just in TableViewController with static cells

Comment: I tried what he did in the tutorial. My code is too messy really it will be understandable as well

Comment: i can help you only if you show me the code

Comment: Alright its pretty complex i hope you understand..

Comment: The code i have right now works but it takes info from the masters cell and send it forward to the detailView what i want for other labels like MusicLabel that it will take data from Label1Data i gave example above you understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141878/discussion-between-ganesh-kumar-and-newbie-questions).

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: @KKRocks look in the discussion maybe you will understand better.

Comment: sorry , i still not able to understand.

Comment: @KKRocks i have a tableViewController with static cells. And i want to change the text of a label  in a cell by an array so the it will change by indexPath.row .... now?

Comment: when you click on mastercontroller then label change in detailviewcontroller ?

Comment: no when i will open the detailView the text will show text by the indexpath of an array... @KKRocks

Comment: @GaneshKumar Can you post an answer saying use a viewController instead or something related i will mark your help as the answer ... kv got no wit working thanks to you! so thank you

Comment: @NewbieQuestions i have posted an answer. check it out.. glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant use a `TableViewController` for your purpose. Instead you can use a normal `ViewController` with labels and textfields.

[image]

In the above picture of yours, you can use a simple `label` of `width = 1` and `color = lightGrey` so that you can get the same separator line as in the tableview.

Comment: Thanks iv changed to viewcontrolller and now everything is working great

Comment: @NewbieQuestions glad it helped :)